# h2 no longer works in AUTO_SERVER mode. Exception in thread "main" org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Feature not supported: "autoServerMode

Tags: java, jdbc, h2

Its brand new stable version of h2 I just downloaded.  has been working great for a week until now.  My error is

```
Exception in thread "main" org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Feature not supported: "autoServerMode && (readOnly || fileLockMethod == NO || fileLockMethod == SERIALIZED || fileLockMethod == FS || inMemory)" [50100-196]
```

I have been using automatic mixed mode for a week now where my backend java program first opens the precreated h2 DB as `"jdbc:h2:./PATH/db;IFEXISTS=TRUE;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE";`

the backend runs perpetually, processing data into DB, so the DB is never closed.  I then have some frontend java servlets that when web users run them, they open the db using same URL, fetch the info, and present HTML.  it was all working, and now the backed fails on opening DB with the same error I get when trying to use the shell tool when tryign the same URL:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Feature not supported: "autoServerMode && (readOnly || fileLockMethod == NO || fileLockMethod == SERIALIZED || fileLockMethod == FS || inMemory)" [50100-196]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getUnsupportedException(DbException.java:216)
        at org.h2.engine.Database.open(Database.java:644)
        at org.h2.engine.Database.openDatabase(Database.java:276)
        at org.h2.engine.Database.<init>(Database.java:270)
        at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:64)
        at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:176)
        at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSessionAndValidate(Engine.java:154)
        at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:137)
        at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:27)
        at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:354)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:116)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:100)
        at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:69)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
        at org.h2.tools.Shell.runTool(Shell.java:148)
        at org.h2.tools.Shell.main(Shell.java:81)
```

I stopped tomcat, tried again, get same thing.  I checked ps, and theres no other java processes running.  Netstat command only shows port 22 LISTENING.  I can open the shell tool on that DB url  *if* I take off AUTO_SERVER=TRUE.  but not sure why.  I even went in and saw a lock file.  I renamed it and tried to open db again in AUTO_MODE, same error.  Not sure what went wrong here, or what to try next.

Comment: Is the database file writeable to the current filesystem user?

Comment: hmm.  actually, i noticed the file owner was root and group was root as well.  im almost positive that when i created it i was a different user, the same user that runs the backend java program.

now, the tomcat server that runs the servlets is root/root.  but the frontend servlets never do any writes/updates, just "select" SQL statements.  but i suppose that somehow this may be related?

if so, im not quite sure the "proper" way to have a backend/frontend cooperation with a central DB.

I run tomcat as root since I want my HTTP server on port 80.

Comment: You shouldnt run tomcat as root, there are ways of using port 80 without doing so. However, just because it is running as root, doesnt mean that the file needs to be owned by root. The root user can read/write any file regardless of who it is owned by, you could try and change ownership to the user that runs the backend, but you might still have issues with ownership of the lock files, im not sure. Generally you should try and ensure that the backend starts first, before the front end, as described in the AUTO_SERVER documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Since version 1.4 of H2, the default `FILE_LOCK` method used is `FS` which **doesn't** work along with `AUTO_SERVER=TRUE`. I'm guessing since you don't explicitly provide a `FILE_LOCK` method in your connection string, once you upgraded your H2 library but didn't change the connection string you started seeing this exception since the library itself internally changed the way it works.